# core php extension upgrade to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome-extension, lumen

I have been given a code of core-PHP which is basically an extension of chrome. It is a content **scraper** type tool which will fetch data and post to our system. Any shared content will be posting on social ids which are attached to it.
Now I am supposed to rebuild the system in laravel and I am getting stuck on how to take this core PHP built code (extension) and re-develop in Laravel. What major changes I will be supposed to? Will this extension be rewritten?
And how that previously written core PHP code will be used in order to develop with laravel.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow! Chrome extensions are written in Javascript. Sounds like your extension uses web services written in the core PHP and that needs to be re written in Laravel. So yes may need to makesome changes in your extension as well if you change your web service's urls or post param.

Comment: i don''t have an idea regarding the extension? can you please give any link ?

Comment: Read documentation here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions